# I filtered the categories but they render all the categories

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

In my DisplayCharacters.jsx I've trying to filter by categories when the user applies filters to the search, and it supposed to render only the categories that the user has applied the filters, but instead, it renders all the categories.

Ex. A user wants to search for a character whose name starts with "S", that is a "Vampire" and also is a "Female".

**React** code below:

```
//This is a function to filter an object
function objectFilter(mainObject, filterFunction){
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(mainObject).filter(objKey => 
  filterFunction(mainObject[objKey[0]])))
};

const filters = objectFilter(this.props.filters, el => el !== null);

filters.lenght > 0 ?
  this.props.data
    .filter(el => {
       if (el.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.props.name.toLowerCase())){
          if(filters.age){
            if(el.age === filters.age){
              return true
            }
          }
          if(filters.gender){
            if(el.gender === filters.gender){
              return true
            }
          }
          if(filters.status){
            if(el.status === filters.status){
              return true
            }
          }
          if(filters.race){
            if(el.race === filters.race){
              return true
            }
          }
        }
        return false
      })
      .map(el =>
         <Character 
           img={el.img}
           name={el.name}
           race={el.race}
           age={el.age}
           status={el.status}
           gender={el.gender}
           key={el.id} />
       )
       :
       this.props.data
         .filter(el => el.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.props.name.toLowerCase()))
         .map(el =>
             <Character 
                img={el.img}
                name={el.name}
                race={el.race}
                age={el.age}
                status={el.status}
                gender={el.gender}
                key={el.id} />
          )
```

`this.props.data` is an array of objects `[{}, {}, {}...]`, each array contains the character info (id, name, race, gender, status, img, etc...).

Comment: Don't tack things onto standard library prototypes, _especially_ not Object. Write it as normal function in a utils.js or something and then import it from there in the files where you need it. Also, since we're using modern JS,  you might not be aware that JS don't need to iterate using `Object.keys`, you can just do `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(...).map(...))` directly, and it's pretty useful ;)

Comment: Hey @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, thanks for your comment! I did it and my code looks so much cleaner and readable. But I still have the same problem T_T

Comment: You have a simple typo here: `filters.lenght > 0 ?` which should be `filters.length > 0 ?` - it might start working now

Comment: On that note, whatever editor you're in: install a typo plugin. In VS Code, install [code spell checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker) and never run into `lenght` or `hight` etc. every again

Comment: @Mikkel, thanks for the typo error advice! I installed the VS Code plugin that @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans suggest and verified the code for other typos. I changed `filters.length` because you can't get the length of an object like that and also added an `else` statement after each validation. Now it works perfectly!!! You guys are amazing, thanks!